# Setting up Karma for an angular library

Tags: angular, unit-testing, typescript, karma-jasmine, gulp-karma

I am currently building an Angular library, and I wanted to be able to run some tests. After following [these](https://github.com/raphael-volt/ng2-testable-lib) instructions I managed to set up everything properly and actually be able to run my tests.

**Main question**

Although everything runs properly something awkward happens. When I run `npm test` next to every `.ts` file a `.js` file is generated. Normally all the `d.ts` and the one big `.js` files go inside a `dist` folder that projects using the library use. So does anyone know from where could these javascript files are generated, and if they are indeed needed, since all this code already exists so to speak in the dist folder.

**Bonus question**

Not as important as the above, all the test results are displayed in the terminal, whereas the browser displays only:

*Karma v1.4.1 - connected
Chrome 61.0.3163 (Mac OS X 10.12.6) is idle*

So is there a nice fix to display my test as nicely as the `angular-cli` does out of the box?

**Note** that after doing my homework I did not find something relative online, and I don't want to upload a bunch of unpleasant jsons. If anyone has an idea on the direction of the problem I will be happy to include code.

The basic structure of my library was generated by [this](https://github.com/jvandemo/generator-angular2-library)

**Edit:**
`karma.config.js`

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
     basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', 'karma-typescript'],
    files: [
    'init-test-bed.spec.ts',
    'src/**/*.ts'
    ],
    exclude: [
    ],
    preprocessors: {
         '**/*.ts': ['karma-typescript']
    },

    karmaTypescriptConfig: {
      bundlerOptions: {
        entrypoints: /\.spec\.ts$/,
        transforms: [
        require('karma-typescript-angular2-transform')
        ]
    },

    compilerOptions: {
        lib: ['ES2015', 'DOM']
    }
},
    reporters: ['progress',  'karma-typescript'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false,
    concurrency: Infinity
})
}
```

`tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "rootDir": "./src",
     "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2015",
      "dom"
    ],
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "types": [
      "jasmine",
      "node"
    ]
  }
}
```

Finally the `test` runs this script

```
"test": "tsc && karma start"
```

Comment: Are you using angular cli? can you share your karma configuration file. and when you run `npm test` what is the command execued in your package.json file

Comment: @AniruddhaDas I am using angular cli for the app that runs the library, not for the library. For the files have a look at my edit.

Comment: See my answer, you are are not using `@angular/cli` framework, all the `ts` files are separately compiled. so adding `"outDir": "../out-tsc/spec"` in your tsconfig.josn should compile all the ts files to js file and add it into a single folder, you can also put in a single file. search for that option in google

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting `.js` file for every .ts file because of your typescript configuration. You can change your configuration in `tsconfig.json` to tell compiler that write a single file or in a folder and add all script there.

`"outDir": "../out-tsc/spec"` --> will add all output javascript files in a single folder.

For your second question, When karma runs internally it runs `webdriver` and connect to the browser. That is the reason you see `localhost:9876` or similar url open with a debug button at the right.

While the webdriver is running you can also debug any bug situation in the browser and lot more.

Comment: So, the `"outDir": "../out-tsc/spec"` .  in the place of `"rootDir": "./src",` solved my main problem.  :)

Still, my second question persists ( I suppose if I research `webdriver` a bit it might be solved ) on why the browser displays nothing else, apart from what I mention on my original question. Any way, a big thanks for your clear answer and well detailed.

Comment: click on the debug button and it will open a new tag with debug. then go to developer mode and find a file and put a break point and refresh page. so when your test case will reach that point it will halt the execution at that point and you can debug. this is basic and it have other facility as well